# How to add placeholder in python for creating table name in mysql database?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-connector

[here i want to name the table name according to user desire but i can't please help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3eJH.png)

** I HAVE INCLUDED THIS CODES FOR CONNECTING PYTHON TO DATABASE **

```html
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector.abstracts import MySQLCursorAbstract
mydb= mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="",database="python")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()`
```

```py
print("do you want to build  table")

g=input()

if(g=='yes'or g=='YES'):

    print("please enter table name")

    enter code here

    k=input()

    mycursor.execute("create table " )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for creating a table in mySql looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table_name (my_first_column INT);
```

This will create the table named "my_table_name" with one column named "my_first_column" of type integer.

To implement this in you can use string formatting

```py
mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE {} (my_first_column INT)".format(k))
```

or if you're using >Python3.7 you can use handy f-strings

```py
mycursor.execute(f"CREATE TABLE {k} (my_first_column INT)")
```

You should also consider sanitzing the users input `k` to prohibit an SQL-injection.